# Can't sign up with parse + react native

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

I try to create sign up feature with parse + react native.
here is what i try:

```html
fetch('https://api.parse.com/1/users', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'AgLXA7Q166mXb5wsD9vfmC7iuFro2Sm4v7Q73h4Q',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'QFJUlRm04A3HaQRA7KOCIPaL8M1x5PKkX2HfUetD',
            'X-Parse-Revocable-Session': '1',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      id: this.state.id,
      password: this.state.password,
      })
    });
```

nothing, happens.
If i try this url:

```html
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/users'
```

I am able to create simple object. 
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with React Native, if you try this request in a fetch-enabled browser then it still seems to fail. If you do this you'll see the following message:

> Fetch API cannot load https://api.parse.com/1/users. Request header
>   field x-parse-revocable-session is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

So if you remove your "X-Parse-Revocable-Session" header from the request then it works. According to the Parse documentation:

> If "Require Revocable Sessions" is turned on (default for new apps),
>   the X-Parse-Revocable-Session header is unnecessary.

Looks like in this case it's being rejected rather than being unnecessary...